# BizTalk Content Based routing issue

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have hit upon a weird problem when trying to use content based routing in BizTalk 2013.

If I have a WCF-BasicHTTP static one-way send port that is subscribing to a message returned from a WCF-BasicHTTP static solicit/response send port, it works fine - my web service is executed as expected.

However, if I have a WCF-BasicHTTP static solicit/response send port that is subscribing to a message returned from a WCF-BasicHTTP solicit/response send port, the webservice executes as expected, but the returning message does not appear.  There is no corresponding tracked message event for the expected receive.  I have debugged the destination webservice and can confirm that it executes and returns the xml document as expected.

In both instances, I am using the XMLTransmit and XMLReceive pipelines.

Furthermore, I have noticed that any send port that subscribes to a message returned from another send port does not have it's adapter details displayed within it's corresponding transmission tracked message event, the adapter value is blank.  I am not sure if this is a clue, but it doesn't seem right.

Can content based routing be used in this way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have a solicit/response port subscribing to the **request** of another solicit/response port, then the response of the subscribing solicit/response port should automatically be routed back to the original port.  You should not need to subscribe to the response of the second solicit/response port.

Comment: I don't, I have a solicit/response port subscribing to a **response** from another solicit/response port, not the request.

Comment: Then try configuring it as per my answer.  A solicit/response port will automatically be subscribing to the response of a request message it published.